# ShareThis: Ign Github - Cant dismiss email pop up on iPad. Requires the app to be closed Edit

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, sharethis

I hope you can help me I am having an issue with dismissing the email pop up on an iPad when I tap the Cancel button nothing happens and the email window remains on screen with no ability to dismiss. Have any of you experienced this issue before ?

Also could you possibly point me to the place in the code where the email dismiss method would be called so as I can attempt to debug ?

Thanks,
Michael

Answer (score 1):

Set delegate for `MFMailComposeViewController` to self.

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mailComposer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mailComposer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

> ```
> //Add this delegate method.
> ```

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    // Remove the email view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution to this issue by updating the ShareThis.m implementation file.

The change made was as below:
Line 171 - ShareThis.m

```
[[[self.viewControllerToShowServiceOn parentViewController] parentViewController] presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Thanks,
Michael